# How to share propertyplaceholder for 2 context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC web application on Spring 3.2.4.
i have 2 context. 
1. mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml look like this :

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ja.dom"/>

    <!-- Tiles 3 config -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <!--Don't add suffix or prefix like you do with .jsp files-->
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" >
        <property name="definitions">
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and 2. root-context.xml like this :

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations" value="classpath:prop.properties"/>
 </bean>

 <!-- Mail Sender Bean -->

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
     <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
     <property name="port" value="587" />
     <property name="username" value="${email.name}" />
     <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />
     <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>

     <property name="javaMailProperties">
         <props>
             <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
             <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
             <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
         </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

When i run application, i see what only mailSender bean have param from properties file.
My other beans, etc @Service .. not be injected. What's wrong? 
How to share my PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to mvc-dispatcher-servlet context?

I inject properties on Service like this :

> @Value("${reCaptcha.private.key}")
>       private String reCaptchaPrivateKey;

and my web.xml **(UPDATE)**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--<init-param>-->
            <!--<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
            <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>-->
        <!--</init-param>-->
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>




    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:prop.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Instead, you should use a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:prop.properties" />
```

Which

> From Spring 3.1 onward, the XML  will no
>   longer register the old PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer but the newly
>   introduced PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This replacement
>   class was created be more flexible and to better interact with the
>   newly introduced Environment and PropertySource mechanism; it should
>   be considered the standard for 3.1 applications.

Comment: 2 Properties placeholder bean for each context file ? Right?

Comment: @jToM One for each, yes.

Comment: This is a best spring practice ?

Comment: @jToM Not necessarily. You can leave all the properties in the same file and have each `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` read from the same place. It just seems to me like it would be good in your situation.

Comment: @JtoM I'm actually wrong. Give me a few minutes, but remove your checkmark.

Comment: @jToM I think the problem is `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Environment doesn't seem to be shared with that. Can you try using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead?

Comment: i use <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:prop.properties" /> but only mailSender bean was injected ( and this server startup log - 01:47:24,422 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] (MSC service thread 1-4) Loading properties file from class path resource [prop.properties] .. PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ! why not PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ?

Comment: i'm use    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">

                <value>classpath:prop.properties</value>

        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean> but this dont work (

Comment: @jToM Are you saying that classes in `com.ja.dom` aren't having their `@Value` resolved? Because it works for me...

Comment: @jToM I don't have either. Take a look at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218694/spring-3-1-propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer-and-conditional-import)

Comment: Well so what impossible ? Only 2 placeholders ? Right?

Comment: @jToM For sure it's possible. More than what I've provided, I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: But it not work for me. Ok. make 2 placeholder. I can put my code to bitbucket if you interested.